# How to make and display notifications in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Before I dive in, This example below is what I hope to achieve.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Meanwhile I Have a database table that is structured like so.

```
CREATE TABLE `notifications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unread` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `reference_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

`recipient_id`  - Notification Reciever
`sender_id` - Notification Sender
`unread` - Mark if notificaton has been read or not
`type` - Holds types of notification, Comment, Likes etc
`reference_id` - the reference like a post id
`created_at` - Time noti was created.
```

and a PHP to fetch data from the database table.

```
$query = $this->database->query("SELECT recipient_id, unread, type, reference_id, post_title, post_name, COUNT(reference_id)
      FROM notifications n INNER JOIN posts p ON p.id = n.reference_id WHERE n.recipient_id = $user AND n.type = 'post_comment' AND n.unread = 1
      GROUP BY n.reference_id HAVING COUNT(n.reference_id) >= 1 ORDER BY unread DESC LIMIT 8")->fetchAll();

      return $query;
```

I'm grouping the results I get by the reference_id if its >= 1
this reason is so I don't get duplicate notification that has the same reference_id.

with this query so far I am able to get the data from the database table and display like so.

> Someone commented on your post "I love to code"

but I want to display to the user like the example above or like this below.

> James, John and others commented on your post "I Love to Code"

thats if there is more than 1 or 2 sender_id with the same reference_id

this is where I am stuck and don't know which other step to take, please any help I can get is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Your combination of selected columns, and what you are grouping over, is illegal in SQL to begin with, only MySQL tolerates this, when in fault-tolerant mode. You can not select columns that are not part of the grouping, outside of any aggregate functions. MySQL will get you a random value from _one_ of the records inside the group here, but that is often not what you’d want to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe what is the best way to do it instead